# Trying to use jQuery Countdown with UNIX timestamp from php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, countdown

As the title says I'm facing a problem displaying the right left time to an end date.

I'm using this jquery plugin: http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html

Let's assume that our timestamp is generated by a PHP script like this: `$end_date = strtotime($row4['end']); // 2012-05-09 06:00:00 becomes 1336536000`

I use this (`$i` is used inside a loop):

```
$('.count-<?php echo $i; ?>').countdown({until: new Date(<?php echo $end_date; ?> * 1000), layout: '{dn} days {hnn} hrs {mnn} min {snn} sec', compact: true});
```

Right now it's 06:21 AM here. Instead of the expected 1 day left result I get "1 days 17 hrs 04 min 21 sec".

What am I missing here?

Comment: $i is a variable that increases through a while loop. `$i = 0; while() { $i++; }` I'm using this because I want to display the countdown to many items.

Comment: I dont want to go into the details of the countdown api, but have you made sure you are working with the same timezone? preferably GMT everywhere.

Comment: OK now I've set both PHP and jquery countdown timezones to GMT 0 but there's still difference between the PHP countdown and the jquery countdown result. PHP countdown result is that 1 day, 1 hour is left and jquery result is 1 days 20 hrs until 2012-05-09 06:00:00.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been using the API for quite a while now, but I cann't seem to figure out what's up with your code. Perhaps (but just perhaps) you're using the `untill` property wrong.

My code that I usually use:

```
$(function(){
    var countdown = $('#countdown'),
        ts = new Date(<?php echo $date_to * 1000; ?>),
        finished = true;

    if((new Date()) > ts)
    {
        finished = false;
    }

    $('#cool-countdown').countdown({
        timestamp   : ts,
        callback    : function(days, hours, minutes, seconds)
        {
            var message = "";

            message += days + " days, ";
            message += hours + " hours, ";
            message += minutes + " minutes, ";
            message += seconds + " seconds ";

            message = (finished ? "Countdown finished" : "left untill the New Year");

            countdown.html(message);
        }
    });

});
```

Obviously you should extend this to feature singular.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Sorry my problem is not with the layout. I think the generated result is wrong. Am I doing wrong the conversion of the UNIX timestamp to a javascript date object?

Comment: @ggirtsou Perhaps try multiplying the $end_date in the server side. E.g. - `...Date(<?php echo ($end_date * 1000); ?>)...`

Comment: OK tried that but still get 1 days 20 hrs for end date 2012-05-09 06:00:00

Comment: @ggirtsou Updated my explanation. Please read thought it and test if it works for you.