# How to make a global countdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok so I am using http://keith-wood.name/ countdown plugin and am using one of the functions for for unix timestamps but need some help.

I will have multiple countdowns around the site but the way I have got it working I have to declare each timer as follows.

```
var crimeTime = new Date();
crimeTime.setTime(<?php echo $crime_time * 1000; ?>);
$('#Crimes').countdown({until: crimeTime, compact: true, format: 'HMS'});
```

and have to repeat the line for each countdown is there a way of making a timer global so for instance...

```
<div class="countdown"><?php echo $unixtimestamp;?></div>
```

I have looked around and tried many but they either do not work at all or do not work with unix timestamp's properly.

another issue is how to get timer to auto start counting down on a submit?

for instance can only do an activity once every 1min the timer displays 00:00:00 once click submit on an activity it stays 00:00:00 it doesn't change to 00:01:00 unless the page is refreshed after submit.

Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10492126/trying-to-use-jquery-countdown-with-unix-timestamp-from-php

Answer (score 0):

You can go in PHP/HTML this way:

```
<div class="countdown" data-time="<?=$unixtimestamp;?>"></div>
```

And in jQuery you do:

```
$('.countdown').each(function(i) {
    var thisCounter = $(this);
    var thisTime = thisCounter.data('time');
    var crimeTime = new Date();
    crimeTime.setTime(thisTime);
    thisCounter.countdown({until: crimeTime, compact: true, format: 'HMS'});
});
```

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't more specific when when I mean global/multiple i ment like different timers for different activities, this way I would still have to define each activity?

So like crimetime is one timer and gtatime is another but want one way of displaying both without having to write multiple lines of jquery.

Comment: @Boxy what do you mean displaying multiple timers without writing multiple lines of code? Just make a function and call it

Comment: I ment like more than one unix timestamp stored in database for different things but want them displayed on one page without having to constantly write same code over and over but just editing it to match another like in my question post.

I will have a look at what you put and have a play after dinner :)

Comment: This is exactly what you want. Just put 10 different timer divs inside your html and run the function above. One function, 10 countdowns.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply need a time counter (to get time in `realtime`) you can make a global one and simply reference to it:

```
timer = new Date().getTime(); // time in miliseconds
timerHolder = setInterval(
  () => {
    timer+= 1000;
  }, 1000
);
```

Then to read the time you can do:
`new Date(timer)`